# Not able to build cordova project for android platform

Tags: cordova

I am new for cordova,phonegap.
I am not able to build for android platform
It is working fine for IOS platform.
I am not able to trace the exact issue.
I remove the fonts and build for android but still getting error.

please see the following screenshot.
And help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @Rahul this issue is not caused by font, this is generic build gradle issue so add this code to your build.gradle file and then build your project again

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```